# php mysql pagination and search between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, search, pagination

when i try to search between two dates on pagination pages, the result come on the first page , and when press next nothing shown

please find the code and try to help please ,
note: i google it but just find pagination with search by name

```js
<script>
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr:odd").addClass("odd");
});

</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
.odd{
 background-color:#ccc;
 
 
 
}
@charset "utf-8";
div.pagination {
 padding: 3px;
 margin: 3px;
}

div.pagination a {
 padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
 margin: 2px;
 border: 1px solid #AAAADD;
 
 text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
 color: #000099;
}
div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
 border: 1px solid #000099;

 color: #000;
}
div.pagination span.current {
 padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
 margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000099;
  
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #000099;
  color: #FFF;
 }
 div.pagination span.disabled {
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
 
  color: #DDD;
 }


</style>
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="topics1.php" method="post">

<input type="date" name="date"/>

<input type="date" name="date1"/>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>

</form>

<br/>
<?php
/*
  date SQL isset
 */
$date1 = isset ($_POST['date']) ? $_POST['date'] : "";
$date2 = isset ($_POST['date1']) ? $_POST['date1'] : "";
 /*
  Place code to connect to your DB here.
 */
 
 $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456','liwa');
 mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8mb4');
  // include your code to connect to DB.

 $tbl_name="sat";  //your table name  
 // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
 $adjacents = 3;
 
 /* 
    First get total number of rows in data table. 
    If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
 */
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name  ";
 $total_pages = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect,$query));
 $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
 
 /* Setup vars for query. */
 $targetpage = "topics1.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
 $limit = 3;         //how many items to show per page
 $page =isset ($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : ""; 
 
 if($page) 
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;//2-1*10  page 2  //first item to display on this page
 else
  $start = 0;        //if no page var is given, set start to 0
 
 /* Get data. */

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM sat 
 WHERE date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
 
  LIMIT $start, $limit ";
 

 $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
 
 /* Setup page vars for display. */
 if ($page == 0) $page = 1;     //if no page var is given, default to 1.
 $prev = $page - 1;       //previous page is page - 1
 $next = $page + 1;       //next page is page + 1
 $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);  //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
 $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;      //last page minus 1
 
 /* 
  Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
  We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
 */
 $pagination = "";
 if($lastpage > 1)
 { 
  $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
  //previous button
  if ($page > 1) 
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\"><< previous</a>";
  else
   $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"><< previous</span>"; 
  
  //pages 
  if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
  { 
   for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
   {
    if ($counter == $page)
     $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
    else
     $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
   }
  }
  elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
  {
   //close to beginning; only hide later pages
   if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))  
   {
    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
    $pagination.= "...";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";  
   }
   //in middle; hide some front and some back
   elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
   {
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
    $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
    $pagination.= "...";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";  
   }
   //close to end; only hide early pages
   else
   {
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
    $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
    }
   }
  }
  
  //next button
  if ($page < $counter - 1) 
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next >></a>";
  else
   $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next >></span>";
  $pagination.= "</div>\n";  
 }
 
 //this is the loop 
?>



 <?php
  echo "<table border='1' width='50%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   
   echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row['Suggestions'];
      echo"</td>";
       echo"<td>";
   echo $row['date'];
      echo"</td>";
  echo"</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  
  
 ?>

<?=$pagination?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for my question, and thanks anyway

```html
<body>

<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(~0);

 $date1 = null;

 if(isset($_POST["date1"]))
 {
  $date1 = $_POST["date1"];
 }
 if(isset($_GET["date1"]))
 {
  $date1 = $_GET["date1"];
 }
 
 
  $date2 = null;

 if(isset($_POST["date2"]))
 {
  $date2 = $_POST["date2"];
 }
 if(isset($_GET["date2"]))
 {
  $date2 = $_GET["date2"];
 }
 
 
?>
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>">
  <table width="599" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Keyword
      <input name="date1" type="date" id="txtKeyword" value="<?php echo $date1;?>">
            <input name="date2" type="date" id="txtKeyword" value="<?php echo $date2;?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">

<br/>
<?php
/*
  date SQL isset
 */

 /*
  Place code to connect to your DB here.
 */
 
 $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456','liwa');
 mysqli_set_charset($connect,'utf8mb4');
  // include your code to connect to DB.

 $tbl_name="sat";  //your table name  
 // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
 $adjacents = 3;
 
 /* 
    First get total number of rows in data table. 
    If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
 */
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name  ";
 $total_pages = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connect,$query));
 $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
 
 /* Setup vars for query. */
 $targetpage = "topics1.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
 $limit = 3;         //how many items to show per page
 $page =isset ($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : ""; 
 
 if($page) 
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;//2-1*10  page 2  //first item to display on this page
 else
  $start = 0;        //if no page var is given, set start to 0
 
 /* Get data. */

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM sat 
 WHERE date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'
 
  LIMIT $start, $limit ";
 

 $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
 
 /* Setup page vars for display. */
 if ($page == 0) $page = 1;     //if no page var is given, default to 1.
 $prev = $page - 1;       //previous page is page - 1
 $next = $page + 1;       //next page is page + 1
 $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);  //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
 $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;      //last page minus 1
 
 /* 
  Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
  We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
 */
 $pagination = "";
 if($lastpage > 1)
 { 
  $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
  //previous button
  if ($page > 1) 
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$prev&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\"><< previous</a>";
  else
   $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"><< previous</span>"; 
  
  //pages 
  if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
  { 
   for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
   {
    if ($counter == $page)
     $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
    else
     $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$counter&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">$counter</a>";     
   }
  }
  elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
  {
   //close to beginning; only hide later pages
   if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))  
   {
    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$counter&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">$counter</a>";     
    }
    $pagination.= "...";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$lpm1&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$lastpage&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">$lastpage</a>";  
   }
   //in middle; hide some front and some back
   elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
   {
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=1&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=2&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">2</a>";
    $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$counter&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">$counter</a>";     
    }
    $pagination.= "...";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$lpm1&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">$lpm1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$lastpage&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">$lastpage</a>";  
   }
   //close to end; only hide early pages
   else
   {
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=1&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">1</a>";
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=2&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">2</a>";
    $pagination.= "...";
    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
    {
     if ($counter == $page)
      $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
     else
      $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$counter&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">$counter</a>";     
    }
   }
  }
  
  //next button
  if ($page < $counter - 1) 
   $pagination.= "<a href=\"$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?page=$next&date1=$date1&date2=$date2\">next >></a>";
  else
   $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next >></span>";
  $pagination.= "</div>\n";  
 }
 
 //this is the loop 
?>



 <?php
  echo "<table border='1' width='50%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   
   echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
   echo $row['Suggestions'];
      echo"</td>";
       echo"<td>";
   echo $row['date'];
      echo"</td>";
  echo"</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  
  
 ?>

<?=$pagination?>
</body>
```